# R: change column order in data.table for only some columns

Tags: r, data.table

I want to sort two columns to the front of my data.table (id and time in my case). Say I have:

```
library(data.table)
Data <- as.data.table(iris)
```

and say I want the order of the columns to be:

```
example <- Data
setcolorder(example,c("Species","Petal.Length","Sepal.Length",
                      "Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width"))
```

but my actual data table has many more variables so I would like to adress this as:

```
setcolorder(Data, c("Species","Petal.Length", 
                    ...all other variables in their original order...))
```

I played around with something like:

```
setcolorder(Data,c("Species","Petal.Length",
                    names(Data)[!c("Species","Petal.Length")]))
```

but I have a problem subsetting the character vector names(Data) by name reference. Also I'm sure I can avoid this workaround with some neat data.table function, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do

```
setcolorder(Data,c("Species","Petal.Length"))
```

similarly as using `xcols` in `kdb q`. `?setcolorder` says:

> If ‘length(neworder) < length(x)’, the
>   specified columns are moved in order to the "front" of ‘x’.

My version of `data.table` is `1.11.4`, but it might have been available for earlier versions too.

Comment: this wasn't available for the version I used back when I asked the question but now it has been for a while so for future reference, this is the correct answer. I changed the accepted answer. I hope akruns reputation score can survive this ;)

Answer (score 10):

We can use `setdiff` to subset all the column names that are not in the subset of `names` i.e. 'nm1', concatenate that with 'nm1' in the `setcolorder`

```
 nm1 <- c("Species", "Petal.Length")
 setcolorder(Data, c(nm1, setdiff(names(Data), nm1)))

 names(Data)
 #[1] "Species"      "Petal.Length" "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Width"
```

A convenience function for this is:

```
setcolfirst = function(DT, ...){
  nm = as.character(substitute(c(...)))[-1L]
  setcolorder(DT, c(nm, setdiff(names(DT), nm)))
} 

setcolfirst(Data, Species, Petal.Length)
```

The columns are passed without quotes here, but extension to a character vector is easy.

Comment: ah, yes, thanks! That makes the workaround work. I'll accept you answer if no data.table solution pops up (I mean the fact that we have to create a vector of all names in the first place seems a bit unelegant, no?)

Comment: you need to create this vector of name, there is no magic in programming.

Comment: well you don't need 'magic'. Here what you'd do in Stata: "order Species Petal.Length" and I though that data.table might have some similar syntax. But still thanks for ruling it out, I accepted the answer.

Comment: @PeterPan Yeah, I also do this somewhat often. It's not hard to write your own `set*` convenience functions / wrappers. I added one to the answer, based on looking at `setkey`. (Just type a function's name to see its code.)

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the function.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally a riff off of Akrun's solution, using a bit more functional decomposition and an anaphoric macro because, well why not.

I'm no expert in writing R macros, so this is probably a naive solution.

```
> toFront <- function(vect, ...) {
   c(..., setdiff(vect, c(...)))
}
> withColnames <- function(tbl, thunk) {
  .CN = colnames(tbl)
  eval(substitute(thunk))
}
> vect = c('c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b')
> tbl = data.table(1,2,3,4,5)
> setnames(tbl, vect)
> tbl
   c d e a b
1: 1 2 3 4 5
> withColnames(tbl, setcolorder(tbl, toFront(.CN, 'a', 'b') ))
> tbl
   a b c d e
1: 4 5 1 2 3
>
```

Comment: nice, thanks! I didn't know you can pass an open list of arguments to a function with `...` .